# Scilab incorrect indices returned when using find command

Tags: csv, find, scilab, indices

I'm relatively new to Scilab and I would like to find the indices of a number in my matrix.

I have defined my number as maximal deformation (`MaxEYY`) and on displaying it, it is correct (I can double check in my *.csv file). However, when I want to know exactly where this number lies in my matrix using the `find` command, only (1,1) is returned, but I know for a fact that this number is located at (4,8).

My matrix is not huge (4x18) and I know that this number only occurs once. On opening the *.csv file, I removed the headers so there is no text.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
N=csvRead("file.csv",",",".",[],[],[],[],1)
EYY=N(:,8);
MaxEYY=max(EYY);
MinEYY=min(EYY);
[a,b]=find(MaxEYY);
disp([a,b]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to understand how `find()` works: it looks for values of true or false in a matrix. So if you want to find a certain value in it, you should do `find(value == matrix)`.

Then, notice that in your code, you are applying `find()` to `MaxEYY`, which is a single value, that is, a scalar, a 1-by-1 matrix. When you do that, you can only get (1,1) or `[]` as results.

Now, combining these two informations, this what you should've done:

```
[a, b] = find(EYY == MaxEYY);
```

Also, there is a quicker way to get this indices: `max()` can also return the indices of the maximum value by doing

```
[MaxEYY, inds] = max(EYY);
```

And the same goes for `min()`.